# Naming multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two sheet I copy to the end of the workbook.

I am trying to name the two sheet the same name via a InputBox and give them two different suffix as standard, the first is "xxx - Project" and the next is "xxx - Report".

I have placed the two sheets in an array. How do I reference the two sheet via the InputBox?

```
Public Sub CopySheets()
    Dim shName As String 'Sheet name var
    Dim shExists As Boolean

    Do

        shName = InputBox("Please enter name of new project", "New Project")

        If shName <> "" Then

            shExists = SheetExists(shName) 'Check for existing sheet name
            If Not shExists Then
                Worksheets(Array(1, 2)).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

            Else
                MsgBox "Project Name:" & Space(1) & shName & " already exists", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Deter"
            End If

        End If

    Loop Until Not shExists Or shName = ""
    End Sub

    Private Function SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String, _
      Optional ByVal wb As Workbook)

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not wb.Worksheets(sheetName) Is Nothing
    End Function
```

Sample image:

[image]

Comment: Refer to the sheets by index.

Comment: Hi BigBen, here you are running late on the renovation job :)
Thanks for the comment I, However, was looking for something more like the original Sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that in in the if conditon

```
    If Not shExists Then
        Worksheets(Array(1, 2)).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1)
        ws.Name = shName & "- project"

        Set ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ws.Name = shName & "- report"

    Else
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Storax exactly what I was trying to do! :) However, the SheetExists Function now doesn't work for some reason? Am I missing the call? FYI: Will vote when Rep is above 15

Comment: Not sure what you mean with _SheetExists Function now doesn't work_. Maybe you open a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that, Rookie mistake. I have created a new question. Thanks for the support.